# Alternate Table Row and Column Color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use the following code to alternate the rows and columns of my table.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("table#id2 td:even").css("background-color", "LightGray");
    $("table#id2 tr:even").css("background-color", "LightBlue");
    $("table#id2 tr:odd").css("background-color", "LightYellow");
  });
</script>
```

When I use this, my 2 column table looks something like this:

```
Gray Blue
Gray Yellow
Gray Blue
Gray Yellow
```

I'd like my table to look like this:

```
Gray Blue
Yellow Yellow
Gray Blue
Yellow Yellow
```

Is this possible using the td:even, tr:odd, etc.. ?

Comment: why jquery  ? why not simple css ?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://devtechie.com/post/2011/09/30/Format-GridView-table-rows-using-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, apply the color only for the `odd` rows 
Try:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("table#id2 td:even").css("background-color", "LightGray");
    $("table#id2 tr:even").css("background-color", "LightBlue");
    $("table#id2 tr:odd td").css("background-color", "LightYellow");
  });
</script>
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rB6Md/)

Comment: Thanks! Had syntax wrong when I tried adding td to code that displays yellow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the background color on `tr:odd td`

```
$("table#id2 td:even").css("background-color", "LightGray");
$("table#id2 tr:even").css("background-color", "LightBlue");
$("table#id2 tr:odd td").css("background-color", "LightYellow");
```

Here's a fiddle showing a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mEFWm/